# Wordpress posts missing but are still visible in database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have an issue where all posts that are older than two days are missing. They are not in the trash in Wordpress, and if you go to the URL, it will come back with a 404.

I've tried disabling all plugins and repairing the tables in PHPMyAdmin as well as using the **/wp-admin/maint/repair.php**

I also have activated wp_debug and looked at the log; however there is nothing relating to this issue.

Now when I check the database in PHPMyAdmin - I can see all the posts there.

I've compared the posts that are currently published to the ones that are missing and the only difference I can see if that the post_status is set to "inherited" opposed to saying "published".

If I update the post_status of a missing post to "published" then edit the post in Wp-admin with the ID, eg, **post.php?post=[missing post id]&action=edit** it will show the missing post for about 2 seconds (including all the content) then redirect to an edit media page with every field blank.

I assume some plugin made this change, figuring out which one is the hard part.

Let me know if you need any more details from my end.

Comment: IIRC `published` is what makes a post visible in Wordpress. Do you have a plugin or a cron job that is changing the older posts' status to `inherited `?

Comment: `inherited` is just a revision of the original post.

Comment: @mr-glass there's no plugin that is modifying existing posts that I'm aware of. Even if there was, would it just move the post to trash or unpublish it so you could still see it in Wordpress?

Comment: Ok I feel like an idiot, the posts are gone, i can just see all the attachments. I think the next step is to extract the wp_posts from the backup database and import them into the current site.

Answer (score 0):

If a post is not viewable in WP dashboard but searchable in SQL table this could mean a revision has not been published (or the published revision has disappeared from the table). To turn on a revision see you must change post_type to 'post' and post_status to 'publish'

make a post viewable in phpmyadmin

[image: 1]